# Redirect htaccess stuggles

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to make a rewrite rule for my website but I cannot seem to get the proper code in order to make this work.

The current URL of my website is looking like `http://www.mohanadarafe.io/JSON/json.html`

I want it to be: `http://www.mohanadarafe.io/json`

I have tried the following code but it does not seem to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.html$ /json [L]
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it reversed. Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /JSON/json\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /json [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one    
RewriteRule ^json/?$ JSON/json.html [L,NC]
```

Then you can have your URL as: `http://www.mohanadarafe.io/json`

Comment: should the file be in the public_html file or the JSON folder?

Comment: It should be in `public_html/.htaccess`

Comment: when someone is on the homepage and goes on the JSON secrtion I want the URL to appear like http://www.mohanadarafe.io/json but its not happening

Comment: it's working but instead of taking the css files from JSON its taking the CSS files from the home page?

Comment: That is how you wrote in your HTML by using relative URLs. To fix, add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/JSON/" />`

Comment: just a question, if I am in json page and I return to index.html, it displays the url as: [www.mohanadarafe.io/index.html#home] how can i avoid this?

Comment: basically, if someone returns to home page I want it to be: www.mohanadarafe.io/ that's it

Comment: Then just change your href to `/` instead of `index.html`